# What is the % operator in `string % variables`?

Tags: python, operators, string-formatting

I thought that `%` (modulo) returned remainders from division but saw this working piece of code and now I'm confused.

Here's the code:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple" : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear" : 3
}

stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple" : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear" : 15
}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
```

My question is specifically about the last 3 lines. What does the `%` do here?

Comment: It's a format specifier: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: for some explanation and examples see: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2):

That is the old string formating operator used to add the values of the dictionaries to the string to be printed.

You can read more about it on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

An example usage is

```
var = 10
var2 = 25.234
str_to_print = "The value of var is %d and of var2 is %0.2f" % (var, var2)
```

A lot of examples and usefull information is available here https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the C `printf` format. Refer to João Almeida's for the docs